# Обработка исключающих ситуации

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Хотел задать вопрос. Я прочитал что такое try-catch и using, Но не понял в чем разница. Пожалуйста объясните. Если можно с примерами для mvc. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`try/catch/finally` - это непосредственно средство языка для обработки исключений (с этим, думаю, всё в целом понятно).
`using` - это синтаксический сахар, используемый в отдельных случаях.
Конструкция `using` используется для объектов, реализующих интерфейс `IDisposable` и предназначен для детерминированной очистки ресурсов (то есть здесь и сейчас).

В чем заключается синтаксический сахар? Поясню на примере. 
Этот код

```
using(var disposable = new SomeDisposableClass())
{
    // какой-то код
}
```

будет развернут компилятором в нечто наподобие

```
var disposable = new SomeDisposableClass();
try
{
    // какой-то код
}
finally 
{
    if(disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Как можно видеть, using - это частный случай использования конструкции `try/catch/finally/`, причем не для всех классов, а только для реализующих интерфейс `IDispoasable`. Как можно заметить, в коде, получающемся из `using`, не используется блок `catch`, то есть любые исключения, выброшенные внутри `using`, будут проброшены наверх.

Почему именно интерфейс `IDisposable`? Это отдельная тема. Вкратце: в C# пользователь не контролирует выделение и очистку памяти напрямую (так как это существенная головная боль), и всю эту рутину на себя берёт сборщик мусора. Сборщик сам удаляет объекты из памяти, и пользователь знать ничего не знает о том, когда и как он это сделает. Но иногда пользователю. нужно освободить те или иные ресурсы здесь и сейчас. Для этого предназначен интерфейс `IDisposable`, у которого есть метод `Dispose`. Если какой-то класс владеет теми или иными управляемыми или неуправляемыми ресурсами, то он должен реализовать этот интерфейс, и освободить их в методе `Disopose` (реализация метода разумеется возлагается на самого программиста). Конструкция `using` позволяет создать такой объект, сделать с ним что-то внутри конструкции, а затем вызвать у него `Dispose`, тем самым освободив его ресурсы тогда, когда это нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Вообще можно использовать try-catch внутри using га? Если можно, приведите пример.

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев можно использовать и внутри и снаружи, но вообще если вам нужен `try/catch`, то также можно использовать его вместо `using`, главное не забудьте в секции `finally` вызвать `Dispose`

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо